# d3 chart won't append to any selector other than body

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm modifying the following code for a stacked bar chart by Mike Bostock from http://bl.ocks.org/yuuniverse4444/8325617 in order to learn d3.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right+legend_width)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

I find that this code only renders just inside the closing body tag. I've tried moving the placement of the script in the page and changing d3.select("body") to d3.select("#chart_name").

Unless I use the term body the chart won't appear at all. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: make sure your javascript is placed after your div in your html page.

Comment: So it's working now- thanks for that :-) I thought I'd tested for that but apparently not.

Comment: Cool. Posting an answer to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Javascript file at the bottom of your DOM structure.

Otherwise, D3 won't be able to make the selection.

Something like:

```
</body>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```